# How to add onkeypress event listener to input tag

Tags: javascript, dom

After I grab an array of input element tags, I try to loop through them adding the *onkeypress* event listener to each one of them.

**My Code:**

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //  Add the event listeners to input tags
    //      Get the array of input tags
    var inputTags = document.getElementsByClassName('validateInput');
    console.log(inputTags);
    //      Loop through them, adding the onkeypress event listener to each one
    for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.lenght; i++)
    {
        var tag = inputTags[i];
        var functionToAdd = function(event, tag)
        {
            isNumberOrDot(event, tag);
        };
        tag.addEventListener('keypress', functionToAdd, false);
    }
};
```

**Question:**

Why isn't `tag.addEventListener('keypress', functionToAdd, false);` not adding the onkeypress event listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have run into 3 issues in your code. First of all don't create functions inside loops, second is closure issue ( you will always get only last `i` value ) , third is that you have typo in `length` property, corrected code should be

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //  Add the event listeners to input tags
    //      Get the array of input tags
    var inputTags = document.getElementsByClassName('validateInput');
    console.log(inputTags);
    //      Loop through them, adding the onkeypress event listener to each one
    var functionToAdd = function(event, tag)
    {
        isNumberOrDot(event, tag);
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++)
    {
        (function( i ) {
            inputTags[ i ].addEventListener('keypress', function( e ) {
                functionToAdd( e, inputTags[i] )    
            }, false);
        })( i );
    }
};
```

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andradei/9yacT/) with your corrections. It is not working still. All I want is for the input tags to have the `onkeypress="isNumberOrDot(event, tag)"` attribute.

Comment: @sargas you have an error in your jsFiddle `Uncaught ReferenceError: isNumberOrDot is not defined` and I can't see where `isNumberOrDot` function defined

Comment: I added to other functions on [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/andradei/9yacT/1/) so you can test it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yacT/2/ . The problem is that `isNumberOrDot` works not as expected + there is no function as `destroyElement` and also you probably may need to use `keyup` event instead of `keypress`

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works great. And yes, "keyup" is exactly what I need in order to delete invalid characters **after** the js script checks if its valid. The script wouldn't delete a character that was pressed (and invalid - not a number of dot) but was not appended in the `input.value` yet. "keyup" lets the script run after the `input.value` is updated with the typed character. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### `.length` is spelled wrong above:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {}
```

Comment: That is only one part of the problem. Once fixed, the solution is not achieved. Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andradei/9yacT/).